# How to add action to the sprite using Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have some sprite which is running some actions.... something like this:

```
[someSprite runAction:someAction]; or [someSprite runAction:someSequence];
```

I need to **add** a **newAction** or newSequence **to the sprite** **to run them after ending of current actions.**

Thanks, George.

Comment: What about any of the callback action that cocos2d has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in someSequence, as the last entry in the list, place a callback with a CCCallFunc (N,ND,O), pointing to a selector of you choice. In the called function, just compute and add the actions you need to add.